# Use recursion to get parent value and children value and all its children's children value

Tags: c#, recursion

Need help with the following question. I was tested on this and failed and really want to know the answer so that I can study it....

Assume an list (C#) of objects in pyramid structure with the following properties:

- id
- name
- value
- parentid

Example (C#):

```
var b = new block();
b.id = 100;
b.name = "block 100"
b.value = 102.50;
b.parentid = 99;
```

Write a recursive function that accepts an ID as the only parameter and will loop through an array or list of an undetermined size and number of levels. The recursive function will calculate

---

```
  block block1 = new block(1, null, "block 1", 11.34M);
    block block11 = new block(11, 1, "block 11", 234.34M);
      block block111 = new block(111, 11, "block 111", 111);
    block block12 = new block(12, 1, "block 12", 564);
    block block13 = new block (13, 1, "block 13", 342.23M);
      block block131 = new block(131, 13, "block 131", 945);
      block block132 = new block(132, 13, "block 132", 10M);
      block block133 = new block(133, 13, "block 133", 88M);
        block block1331 = new block(1331, 133, "block 1331", 45);

  block block2 = new block(2, null, "block 2", 234);
  block block3 = new block(3, null, "block 3", 1249.34M);

  blocks = new List<block>();
  blocks.Add(block1);
  blocks.Add(block11);
  blocks.Add(block111);
  blocks.Add(block12);
  blocks.Add(block13);
  blocks.Add(block131);
  blocks.Add(block132);
  blocks.Add(block133);
  blocks.Add(block1331);
  blocks.Add(block2);
  blocks.Add(block3);

  decimal sum = SumAll(1);
  Console.WriteLine(sum);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

I need a function that gives me a total "value" from the "value" property for the parent and all of its children and its children's children. Can anyone help?

---

```
public class block
{
    public block() { }

    public block(int id, int? parentid, string name, decimal value)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentid = parentid;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public int? parentid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question; don't try to paste code in comments.

Comment: Also: you need to ask a more specific question. "Please implement this program from my copy+pasted spec" is not a question. What is wrong with the code you wrote? Post your attempt, and explain exactly what it does incorrectly.

Comment: looks like you didn't finish your question...

Comment: Sorry, it was my first post on stack overflow and I rushed through the posting as well. mmcrae understood exactly what I meant, and his function worked for me! Thanks so much mmcrae!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you moving (and hopefully editing your question with what you've tried so far), you want something like this:

```
// defined at class level/scope outside method
private List<block> blocks;

...

private int SumAll(int id) {
      var initialBlock = blocks.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id == id);
      int value = initialBlock.Value;

      var childBlocks = blocks.Where(b => b.parentId = id).ToList();
      foreach (var childBlock in childBlocks) {
            // recursive call for children
            value += SumAll(childBlock.id);
      }

      return value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var lookup = blocks.ToLookup(x => x.parentid, x => x.id);
var map = blocks.ToDictionary(x => x.id);
Func<int, decimal> sumAll = null;
sumAll = n => map[n].value + lookup[n].Select(x => sumAll(x)).Sum();
```

Just call `sumAll(1)`.

---

```
public decimal SumAll(List<block> blocks, int id)
{
    return SumAll(id, blocks.ToLookup(x => x.parentid, x => x.id), blocks.ToDictionary(x => x.id));
}

private decimal SumAll(int id, ILookup<int?, int> lookup, Dictionary<int, block> map)
{
    return map[id].value + lookup[id].Select(x => SumAll(x, lookup, map)).Sum();
}
```

Just call `SumAll(blocks, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. A bit complicated for my level, but I'll definitely study this.

Comment: @HarrisStephanie - Is this better?

Comment: Yes but the original requirement was that you could only pass the parent id. If there wasn't that restriction this works nicely. Thanks again!

Comment: @HarrisStephanie - With that restriction then you must have `List<block> blocks` as a class-level variable. This is a bad design. It's better to pass it in.

Comment: interesting approach - but a bit hard to read/complicated depending on one's LINQ familiarity

Comment: @mmcrae - You're probably right, but I do like `map[n].value + lookup[n].Select(x => sumAll(x)).Sum();` as it is quite clear once you understand what `map` and `lookup` do.